# Python code in two-column document

Tags: listings, two-column, code, overfull

I want to put my python code in a two-column document. I am using the `listings` package with the following preamble:

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=true,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}
```

I have the python code as a .py file, and am using it in the body like this:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{<filename>.py}
```

But, the result is like the image below.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to bring the code inside the margins?

Comment: You use `breakatwhitespace` but you don't introduce any to break at. Include some space around the commas and/or operators.

Comment: Note that in Python, a line break is syntactically important (for instance your `A = \n` will lead to a syntax error because of your automatic line breaking). I'd suggest to either manually format your Python code to be syntactically correct and fit the margin, or add an automatic line break character (forgot the name of the option) to make sure your readers get that this should be in the same line as the above.

Comment: @Skillmon I am not able to make the code fit the margin and also keep it syntactically correct, but the option you mentioned seems to be prebreak/postbreak, and it works.  I can only insert newlines at whitespaces as Werner pointed out. It does look a bit ugly though, but I can figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @curious_direwolf of course you can write syntactically correct python that fits the margin, 42 characters per line is easily enough to make it work.

Comment: For instance, inside of parentheses Python reads multiple lines until the delimiters are balanced. Also you can concatenate multiple lines by putting a backslash at the end of the line.

Comment: @Skillmon Okay! I will incorporate these and format my code.

Comment: Also, note that your axis labels don't follow recommended style. Instead of labels like "delay (ns)" you should write "delay / ns" (or better yet, if there is a variable name for "delay" you'd write something like `r"delay $d / \unit{ns}$"` with `siunitx` loaded and the `pgf` backend of matplotlib).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reformats your code to easily fit the margin and is syntactically correct Python code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=true,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
plt.errorbar(delay, TB, np.sqrt(TB/10))

i_max = np.argmax(TB)
print(delay[i_max])

plt.axvline(delay[i_max], linestyle='-',
            color='g', label='-2.5')

plt.xlabel('delay (ns)')
plt.ylabel('Coincidence rate (Hz)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

GRA_coincidence = np.zeros(6)
GRA_coincidence_acc = np.zeros(6)
GRA_SNR = np.zeros(6)
GRA_SNR_error = np.zeros(6)
GRA_RB = np.zeros(6)
GRA_RT = np.zeros(6)
Racc = np.zeros(6)
plt.figure()
for i in range(6):
    A = '/content/coinc/coincidence' + \
        str(i + 1) + '.csv'
    res = read_gra(A)
    B = '/content/coinc/accidental' + \
        str(i + 1) + '.csv'
    res_acc = read_gra(B)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This version has no syntax highlighting though.

Comment: @Marijn just a `language=Python` missing...